# Require JSON to have an element

Tags: postgresql, psql, json

When working with the `json` datatype, is there a way to ensure the input JSON must have an element?

I don't mean primary, I want the JSON that gets inserted to at least have the *id*, *name* element. It can have more but at the minimum those two must be there. Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a column check:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD
  CHECK ((column->'id') is not null and (column->'name') is not null);
```